# How to edit CSS style sheet after migrating from local

Tags: css, localhost

Apologies if this is a stupid question, this is my first time making a webstie. I created a child theme hosted on my computer using Local by Flywheel, edited the CSS to my satisfaction using Atom, then exported the wpress file and uploaded it to a live wordpress site hosted by Godaddy. Everything is working properly but now I want to keep making changes to the CSS.

My question is do I have to make those changes on the stylesheet of the  .local website, export, then re-upload to the live website every time? Or is there a way I can edit the css style sheet of the live website and have those changes take place immediately?

Where is the stylesheet of my now live website and how do I edit it?

Comment: "then exported the wpress file and uploaded it to a live wordpress site" how did you do that?

Comment: Using the "all-in-one migration" plug-in.

Comment: Have you read [this support article on editing files](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-files/)?

Comment: After reading the article you suggested and learning more about FTP I was able to connect to my server using Cyberduck and access all the files. However, when I make changes to the CSS stylesheet, overwrite it in Cyberduck and click upload, I'm not seeing my style changes reflected. I also tried forcing the browser to not use caches to no avail. I tried initially to use Filezilla instead of cyberduck but the program froze for me every time I tried to add my site. I'm using a mac.

Comment: I know I have a working connection with Cyberduck and my website because when I upload plug-ins to cyber duck they appear within the plug-in section of the admin panel of my Wordpress site. But CSS changes don't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having this same problem- after deactivating the "All-in-one migration" plug-in, my changes to the CSS stylesheet took effect on the live website.